# The "Hello World!" box is surrounded by paragraph tags twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, design

Looking at the source of the `Hello World!` box, you see this:

```
<p><p>This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for <b>professional and enthusiast programmers</b>. It's 100% free, no registration required.</p></p>
```

There are two opening `<p>` tags and two closing `</p>` tags, which the browser interprets as this:

```
<p></p>
<p>This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for <b>professional and enthusiast programmers</b>. It's 100% free, no registration required.</p>
<p></p>
```

and produces this [validation error](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2):

> Error *Line 2786, Column 177*: **No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.**
>
> ```
> …d enthusiast programmers</b>. It's 100% free, no registration required.</p></p>
> ```

This error is the only one preventing the front page of Stack Overflow from being "valid" HTML5.

Comment: fixitfixitfixit

Comment: I imagine the scope that the validation error refers to is the parser/tokenizer resolving the first closing `</p>` tag thus no longer being in the *scope* of a paragraph, then encountering the second closing `</p>` tag which it's not expecting anymore since the last paragraph was just closed.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: The error was referring to the `scoped` attribute that was supposed to be on the `<style>` element (which I have personally never heard of before). The link to its corresponding documentation was dead, though.

Comment: @animuson: Ah, scoped stylesheets in HTML5/CSS. I've heard passing mentions of them in the www-style lists, but don't know much about them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed and will be rolling out with the next build.