# Stack Overflow Isn't Valid HTML5

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The “Hello World!” box is surrounded by paragraph tags twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122738/the-hello-world-box-is-surrounded-by-paragraph-tags-twice)

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)  isn't valid HTML5.  There's an extra `</p>` in the "Hello World!" box.

[See for yourself](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://stackoverflow.com/) ([meta is fine](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) however).

I think the Stack Overflow programmers should take time out of their busy schedules to fix this terrible mistake. (*sarcasm*, but I just kinda wanted to point this out)

Comment: [All I want to say is...](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Comment: @Bart: [My thoughts exactly](http://www.eeyup.com/).

Comment: Cue thematic music: [Dun dun DUNNNNNNN!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Chaos)

Comment: Perhaps this should be added here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128548/130994

Comment: @JohnMcG: I lol'd.